# Why Can Prostitutes Come to Solomon?

Tags: sexuality

According to 1 Kings 3:16-28, two prostitutes came to Solomon for a judgment over their dispute concerning a child.

> Then two prostitutes came to the king and stood before him... Then the king answered and said, “Give the living child to the first woman,
>   and by no means put him to death; she is his mother.” And all Israel
>   heard of the judgment that the king had rendered, and they stood in
>   awe of the king, because they perceived that the wisdom of God was in
>   him to do justice.

If prostitution was illegal (more specifically, if sex outside marriage is condemned by God), why were they willing (perhaps even comfortable) coming to the king and admitting to be prostitutes?

One of our assumptions must be false. Which ones?

So, what's the explanation?

In fact, one of the highly voted answer in this site, claim that sex outside marriage is never prohibited at all.

> There is no evidence that pre-marital sex is an instance of porneia,
>   nor is there any prohibition of responsible pre-marital sex stated in
>   Scripture.
>   [What's is the case for premarital sex being an instance of πορνεία (porneia)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/778/is-premarital-sex-porneia?lq=1)

I need factual answers. For example, if some says that prostitution is illegal but by God's grace, prostitutes deserve justice and come to Solomon, then I would need to see more evidences. Perhaps, some historians could tell that prostitution is indeed illegal during 2500 ago in Israel with penalty of stoning or what, etc and somehow the Solomon didn't punish the prostitutes that come to him despite knowing full well what their jobs are. I wonder if it's likely?

Comment: There are different types of laws in the Torah as there are in society today. One must make a distinction between moral laws, ordinances, and civil laws that are made in the Torah. Also, what Scripture are you speaking about specifically?

Comment: I have given you a down vote, because your question defies one of the 10 commandments Deuteronomy 5:18  Neither shalt thou commit adultery.

Comment: What does adultery (screwing someone else' wife) have anything to do with prostitution (getting paid for having sex)?

Comment: @ Sharen Eayrs Even if you hold to the strict definition of Adultery today which by the way is not the same as the original Hebrew word used which is  נאף and can be committed before marriage why would you want to legitimize it?

Comment: I am not trying to legitimize it. I want to know the truth. Someone else try to legitimize it and I want to verify their claim here.

Comment: This seems to be valid question and is misunderstood because it is not worded properly.  The question is something like this: Two robbers are fighting over their booty which they robbed overnight. They come to their King, who is also judge and ask for justice from him in deciding who can take that booty. So here instead of arresting these robbers how can judge give his decision on ownership of the booty?

Comment: In similar manner, here one of the two prostitutes child dies and they are now fighting for possession of a child who is alive. The question is: Instead of judging on their conduct how King Solomon could give justice on the possession of the child?  The short answer could be that King Solomon had no idea that they were Prostitutes.

Comment: That could be a short answer. So it's not obvious. However, if they're not prostitutes, what else they could be? Engineers? Programmers? Housewives (without husband)? And you think someone as wise as Solomon that can decide motherhood without genetic testing couldn't figure out the women's occupation?

Comment: what are you asking?  are you asking if Solomon broke laws? are you asking if Solomon was acting on some law or rule by not calling them out on their law breaking habits?  are you asking about what kind of ruler Solomon was?  you ask many questions here which one is the question for this question?

Comment: I am asking if prostitution is even illegal in the first place

Answer (score 12):

This question is predicated on completely faulty assumption - namely that criminals do not come to the palace to seek justice.  At that time, the King was also the judge, and the judge was specifically ordered to give justice to all.

The prophets are replete with invective against those hypocritical government officials who would only seek justice for those on top of society.  As just one example, [Amos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Amos#Themes) goes out of his way to say that Israel is under the same condemnation as its neighbors. Leviticus demands [one law for you and the alien in your midst](http://www.biblestudytools.com/leviticus/24-22-compare.html) - again, fairness for *everyone.* When the Scripture commands that the judge give justice to the poor as well as to the widow and the orphan, the clear indication is that justice shouldn't depend on your status in society.  Indeed, for many at the time, the poor and the criminal would have occupied similar places in the mind.

Thus, when two women of whatever station came to Solomon, asking for justice in regards to the one living child, Solomon, in the wisdom that God gave him, would necessarily give justice to *anyone* who came to seek it.  What these women were outside of this case is 100% irrelevant in the face of a God who sees all in place of judgement, all who are unworthy.

As Isaiah says, "All we like sheep have gone astray, each to our devices" and "all our righteousness is as filthy rags."

As Judah says to Tamar - a woman who has played the prostitute and slept with her own father-in-law (him!) in order to get pregnant, "You are more righteous than I!"

And, as Jesus, who modelled this radical love showed, justice belongs even to the prostitutes and even worse, the tax collectors.  After all, those who are healthy do not need the Great Physician.  But our God showed his love for us in this - while we were yet *sinners* he died for us.

---

Note: convicted criminals use courts all the time.

- http://articles.washingtonpost.com/2011-09-08/local/35275281_1_strip-club-aids-funds-lawsuit
- http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/bronx/drug-dealer-suing-state-keeping-dying-mother-article-1.1444094

and in this instance [an Iowa man called the cops when he was stiffed in a drug deal](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2013/oct/9/iowa-man-calls-cops-i-was-stiffed-drug-deal/).  Google "[criminals do stupid things](https://www.google.com/search?q=criminals+do+stupid+things&oq=criminals+do+stupid+things&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5868j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)" for more results.

Directly to the question, however:

1. Prostitution was illegal under Jewish law, as per [Deuteronomy 23:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2023.18&version=ESV)
2. Prostitution was [rather common](https://sites.google.com/site/hashtaumd/contents-1/prost) however.
3. This toleration of an otherwise illegal activity, merely supports what is written above - namely that prostitutes would have been legally culpable and socially marginalized, but that justice demanded that they be heard in spite of their status.

Comment: My 500th answer. I love this place

Comment: Well done! Hate having to vote you up for it after losing all my points but excellent answer.

Comment: So what you are trying to say is that those prostitutes are criminal. People know it. They come the palace and don't get punished. Can anyone confirm that it's true? That prostitutes are criminal historically during Solomon era?

Comment: @SharenEayrs I'm not understanding your comment.  You were saying '{people who sin} can't get justice' and you were using the term criminal.  I am saying, that's just silly - we're all guilty before God, and we are all still entitled to justice.  Your question is nonsensical at best and based on heresy at worst.

Comment: Just because someone has sinned does not mean they should be excluded from justice or even from the church for that matter. My point was, these were the people Jesus loved, and so should we!

Comment: I am not asking whether prostitutes should be excluded from justice or not. I am asking whether going to a king for justice is a reasonably practical way in ancient Israel. Should drug lords settle their disputes in court? Could be. Do they? No.

Comment: @SharenEayrs Should a drug lord who has a dispute over something related to a legal matter (such as poor representation) settle his/her dispute in court?  Certainly!  The prostitutes were not disputing over Johns.  They were disputing over the lives of their children.

Comment: @SharenEayrs are you asking a question or fishing for someone to agree with you?

Comment: I am asking a question. I want to know whether prostitution were legal or not during Solomon era. It seems to me, openly criminals people can come to court in Solomon era. That's something I want to know. Can you cite sources? Are there any other answers?

Comment: Did you see the sources I linked in points 1 and 2 at the end?

Comment: Do you have sources indicating that prostitution were illegal during solomon era?

Comment: Did you read point 1?

Comment: Actually one of your link shows the strangeness of your point. https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2013/oct/9/iowa-man-calls-cops-i-was-stiffed-drug-deal/ when drug dealers call cops, they get arrested. That's usually what happen.